# How can I define a structure of a json to transform it to csv

Tags: python, json, dataframe

I have a json structured as this:

```
    { 
 "data": [
   {
      "groups": {
         "data": [
               {
               "group_name": "Wedding planning - places and bands (and others) to recommend!",
               "date_joined": "2009-03-12 01:01:08.677427"
               },
               {
               "group_name": "Harry Potter and the Deathly Hollows",
               "date_joined": "2009-01-15 01:38:06.822220"
               },
               {
               "group_name": "Xbox , Playstation, Wii - console fans",
               "date_joined": "2010-04-02 04:02:58.078934"
               }
         ]
      },
      "id": "0"
   },
   {
      "groups": {
         "data": [
               {
               "group_name": "Lost&Found  (Strzegom)",
               "date_joined": "2010-02-01 14:13:34.551920"
               },
               {
               "group_name": "Tennis, Squash, Badminton, table tennis - looking for sparring partner (Strzegom)",
               "date_joined": "2008-09-24 17:29:43.356992"
               }
        ]
      },
      "id": "1"
   }
 ]
}
```

How does one parse jsons in this form? Should i try building a class resembling this format? My desired output is a csv where index is an "id" and in the first column I have the most recently taken group, in the second column the second most recently taken group and so on.

Meaning the result of this would be:

```
      most recent                               second most recent
0     Xbox , Playstation, Wii - console fans    Wedding planning - places and bands (and others) to recommend!
1     Lost&Found  (Strzegom)                    Tennis, Squash, Badminton, table tennis - looking for sparring partner (Strzegom)
```

Comment: If it's a one-off, a class seems excessive. Just loop over the items in `data` in each sorted group and stop after two iterations.

Comment: Tangentially, your desired result looks rather unappetizing. What problem are you actually trying to solve?

Comment: I want to feed the text to neural network along with another text column I have in another csv, so I figured the best would be to have it in csv? Why does it look unappetizing?

Comment: If you aren't hellbent on using Python for this, `jq 
-r '.data[].groups.data|=sort_by(.date_joined)|.data[]|[.id, .groups.data[0].group_name, .groups.data[1].group_name]|@csv'` comes close ... see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35540294/sort-descending-by-multiple-keys-in-jq for how to reverse the sort.

Comment: Having two textual columns just looks unnatural; maybe instead add a priority like maybe 0,0,Xbox; 0,1,Wedding planning; 1,0,Lost & Found; 1,1,Tennis, Squash

Answer (score 0):

solution could be like this:

```
data = json.load(f)
result = []
# it's max element in there for each id. Helping how many group_name here for this example [3,2]
max_element_group_name = [len(data['data'][i]['groups']['data']) for i in range(len(data['data']))]
max_element_group_name.sort()

for i in range(len(data['data'])):
    # get id for each groups
    id = data['data'][i]['id']
    # sort data_joined in groups
    sorted_groups_by_date = sorted(data['data'][i]['groups']['data'],key=lambda x : time.strptime(x['date_joined'],'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f'),reverse=True)
    # get groups name using minumum value in max_element_group_name for this example [2] 
    group_names = [sorted_groups_by_date[j]['group_name'] for j in range(max_element_group_name[0])]
    # add result list with id
    result.append([id]+group_names)

# create df for list
df = pd.DataFrame(result, columns = ['id','most recent', 'second most recent'])
# it could be better.
```